# iOS: UIView vs. SKView

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, skview

I am creating a game that involves mini-games inside of separate levels (laid out in picture). I started by using `UIViewController`, but once some of the levels needed animations and gravity, I wanted to switch to `SKView`, because doing all of those animations by hand is not efficient. I have already created the menu and a few of the level packs using `UIViewController`, and changing all to SKView would be a hassle at this point. With this in mind, what is the best practice for creating views and what is the best "combination", so to speak, of `UIViewController` and `SKView`? Is it better to use one for the main menu and the other for the games? All help is appreciated!

[image: Mapped View]

Comment: There is nothing to stop you using UIViews and SKViews in one game. Only use the SKViews where you need them just add one as a subview of your UIView and do all the complex stuff inside there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I feel that working with SKViews are a little more of a hassle then working with UIViews, however if you are interested in making a menu system thats very animation rich (which most good games do) then I recommend putting up with it and going all SKView. Cause thats the easiest route of doing so.  If you could care less, stick with what you know and go UIView.  O, Or, you can have a UIView initially, and have a small portion of the screen be a UIView u turn declare as an SKView for displaying of scenes.  Your call.